# Detect if the caller has access to my assembly internals

Tags: c#, internal

I need to detect in a method if its caller has internal access to my assembly. That is, if it is a) code in the same assembly or b) has a InternalsVisibleTo relationship with my assembly. Ideally the check should be fast.

What are my options?

UPDATE:
I would also be partially satisfied if there was a good solution for part a of the problem.

Comment: What kind of hellhole do you work in?

Comment: I've provided an answer - but out of interest can you explain WHY you want to do this?  Maybe there is a better solution to the problem in general.

Comment: Sure there are other solutions, but I can only rank them from better to worse, once I know each one. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into System.Diagnostics.StackTrace

```
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
    MethodBase mb = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    Assembly a = mb.DeclaringType.Assembly;
```

a) just compare current assembly to a

b) i think you should be able to pick out the InternalsVisibleTo attributes on the assembly

Comment: I guess this fails the "ideally the check should be fast" constraint, but I think this is probably the only reliable way.

Comment: Much faster than the time they'll waste unpicking the holy mess of code that results if they use this to implement caller dependent behaviour...

Comment: I agree. CAS would be more appropriate here.

Comment: How would a CAS solution look like?

Comment: I think x0n is referring to the code access security in .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(VS.80).aspx. This doesn't explicitly provide a solution to your question but may be a better solution to the underlying problem depending on what that is, i.e. depends why you need to know the caller.  Generally CAS allows you to control access to code depending on some external conditions.

Comment: I think this is the best we are going to get, even though it does not fulfill the speed requirement.

Comment: Thanks.  If you're app design is such you get a lot of repeat callers to these methods then make sure your memoize the process and speed shouldn't be an issue.